# vbCrLf keeps replacing text in a text box when it's meant to be displaying the next block of text below it

Tags: vb.net

I'm building a program in which it asks for your name and age and determines a ticket price based upon these details. I want it to show the person's name, then their age, (jump down a line) then their ticket price, and then it jumps down a line to show the next person's name, age and ticket price. Issue is, when it's meant to jump down to show the next person, it just completely deletes the last person's details.

I'm using this line of code:

```
TxtFareShow.Text = (Name & Age & vbCrLf & Price) & vbCrLf
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
TxtFareShow.Text = TxtFareShow.Text & (Name & Age & vbCrLf & Price) & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Good, but for some reason it shows two copies of the same thing

Comment: Make sure you clear the textbox before adding the first item, otherwise you'll just append more information... again... every time you execute the code.